# Error while trying command: php yii migrate in terminal

Tags: php, yii, command, migrate

I had errors while trying the command:

php yii migrate

A PDO driver error or other errors shown

Answer (score 0):

After trying many solutions I got the answer:

1)I just uninstalled xampp on my computer from control panel

2)Downloaded and Installed xampp version 7.4.6

3)Downloaded and intalled composer pointing the required php.exe to C:\xampp\php\php.exe which was my xampp installation folder

4)Finally re run php yii migrate and it is successful